# how to make a blocked matrix?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

suppose I have the following matrix

```
         1   2   3
         4   5   6
         7   8   9
```

and I want to make a block matrix like:

```
         1   2   3   0   0    0   0   0   0   0    0   0  
         4   5   6   0   0    0   0   0   0   0    0   0
         7   8   9   0   0    0   0   0   0   0    0   0
         0   0   0   1   2    3   0   0   0   0    0   0 
         0   0   0   4   5    6   0   0   0   0    0   0
         0.  0   0   7   8    9   0   0   0   0    0   0   
         0   0   0   0    0   0   1   2   3   0    0   0    
         0   0   0   0    0   0   4   5   6   0    0   0   
         0   0   0   0    0   0   7   8   9   0    0   0   
         0   0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1    2   3   
         0   0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4    5   6   
         0   0    0   0   0   0   0.  0   0   7    8   9
```

I did following :

```
   BigKernel<-Matrix::bdiag(replicate(4, m1, simplify = FALSE))
```

but the problem is that BigKernel is not a matrix. when I do

```
 as.matrix(Bigkernel)
```

it is false. and types(Bigkernel) is S4.

How I can make a matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`R` is case-sensitive.  `BigKernel` and `Bigkernel` are different

```
as.matrix(BigKernel)
```

should work